# Real Time FFT Plotting In Python ( MatPlotLib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft, pyaudio

I have an incoming audio stream via my microphone which pyaudio is reading, im performing FFT calculations to that data and what i would like is to plot the FFT amplitude data on the Y axis, and the FFT frequency Data on the X axis and have it update at (lets say 20fps for example), basically to look like this ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tu8p2pywJAs&t=93s ) but with the low frequencies on the left and the higher frequencies on the right.    The code i have is as far as i have got

i am new to python, let alone to coding of any way shape or form so any help is appreciated but please try and keep it to understandable terms, if i ask to elaborate please do so with respect, thankyou very much to anyone who gives me their time!

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

callback_output = []

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    audio_data = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.int16)
    callback_output.append(audio_data)
    return None,pyaudio.paContinue


stream = pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                 channels=1,
                 rate=44100,
                 output=False,
                 input=True,
                 stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw()

while stream.is_active():
    fft_data = np.fft.fft(callback_output)
    fft_freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft_data))
    plt.plot(fft_freq,fft_data)
    plt.xlim(min(fft_freq),max(fft_freq))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.05)
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    fig.clear()

stream.close()
pa.terminate()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't generate data for you but I wrote an example which updates a matplotlib graph in a loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time


plt.ion() # Stop matplotlib windows from blocking

# Setup figure, axis and initiate plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro-')

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # Get the new data
    xdata = np.arange(10)
    ydata = np.random.random(10)

    # Reset the data in the plot
    ln.set_xdata(xdata)
    ln.set_ydata(ydata)

    # Rescale the axis so that the data can be seen in the plot
    # if you know the bounds of your data you could just set this once
    # so that the axis don't keep changing
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()

    # Update the window
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

You should just be able to change the lines where xdata and ydata are assigned in the loop to get it working for your data.

If you want to get the low frequencies on the left you might want to look at using np.fft.fftshift on fftfreq and fftdata: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html

Comment: hi, trying that aswell as other methods is giving me some incredibly weird looking graphs, they are updating in what i think is real time but they make no sense visually, by any chance are you able to use the code i have created and you're solution and tell me if you are also getting weird results

Comment: Is it plotting the data and you're just getting a weird result from the Fourier transform. I can't check your code because I don't have a microphone. Can you include a photo of your plot?

Comment: A couple of things that could be a problem. 1) You're appending to your callback_output list rather than overwriting - is this your intended behaviour. 2) You're not providing a sample spacing to fftfreq which could be a problem. You should pass d=1/44100 to the fftfreq call so you get fft_freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft_data), d=1/44100)

Comment: im now using audio_data as a global variable and it does clear the graph properly, however im getting results with lines going really far up and really far down, its the axis changing but i dont know how to set it as a fixed axis :(,  also i have set the sample rate since your reply, its just the axis changing, there is also some vertical lines ( which i believe is the amplitude ) and its always being drawn pretty far positive and negative on the 0 frequency value, its only the Y axis which is changing which is my fft_data ( not my fft_freq )  i am also not sure how to post a photo in comments

Comment: ah i used sharex to upload a gif of the plot, https://i.imgur.com/iVDVwS8.gifv    the last 2 or 3 seconds when there is 2 large vertical lines was when i was whistling, the rest i presume is background noise but there are some very odd anomalies which i think the axis is re-adjusting to, how would i make it fixed

Comment: when i did what you said with just setting the axis scaling once, it just becomes random scale based on the first chunk of audio data, so thats not working :(

Comment: The Fourier transform looks as I would expect for an audio signal, you could use np.abs to make the signal all positive. As for the range you'll just have to guess an appropriate range and choose that. Maybe try ax.set_ylim([0, 1]) and change these values until it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code:

```
while stream.is_active():
    fft_data = np.fft.rfft(callback_output) # rfft removes the mirrored part that fft generates
    fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(callback_output), d=1/44100) # rfftfreq needs the signal data, not the fft data
    plt.plot(fft_freq, np.absolute(fft_data)) # fft_data is a complex number, so the magnitude is computed here
    plt.xlim(np.amin(fft_freq), np.amax(fft_freq))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.05)
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    fig.clear()
```

Comment: thanks for comment, but this has been solved, i finished my project and learnt alot on the way, hopefully this comment helps somebody else who is searching for similar thing